# How do I start an animation by means of ButtonClick event?

Tags: c#, wpf, animation

I have some challenges with a code as follows.
I need to start this simpliest animation code by means of e.g. ButtonClick event or a method in Code Behind.
Could anyone shed the light on this matter?

Update: The code itself is working perfectly. I need just start it by a button. Not while window loading.

Thanks in advance!

```
    <StackPanel>

        <Button x:Name="Button" Content="Start" Click="Button_Click"/>
    </StackPanel>

    <Image
        Name="img"
        Width="128"
        Height="128">
        <Image.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Source" Duration="0:0:2.0">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                    <BitmapImage UriSource="D://Speakers//Wave_00.png" />
                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:.5">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                    <BitmapImage UriSource="D://Speakers//Wave_01.png" />
                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                    <BitmapImage UriSource="D://Speakers//Wave_02.png" />
                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1.5">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                    <BitmapImage UriSource="D://Speakers//Wave_03.png" />
                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>

                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Image.Triggers>
    </Image>

</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

try to change

eventtrigger routedevent="loaded"

in

EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button_Click"

i hope it works

Comment: That's the point, there's not an event Button_Click for that. )

Comment: @Pew its Button.Click not Button_Click and loaded is not loaded its Element(e.g window) Element.Loaded